# 2 tab excel sheet to 2 excel in python aws databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am using AWS data bricks Python with version 3.9.5, need a Py spark query to split a single excel into multiple excel based out of its sheets.

Comment: Do you have an example and what have you tried?

Comment: excel file name in s3 source location as abc_MMDDYYYY.xlsx has two tabs in it (xyz and def)

need xyz_MMDDYYYY.xlsx and def_MMDDYYYY.xlsx at target s3 location

Comment: You just need pandas to do this. here's an excellent answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402374/3238085